Diode current voltage characteristic issues
I'm trying to find the current-voltage characteristic of a red LED diode in the biggest possible range using five 3 V batteries, one 100 Ω resistor and ten diodes, but my graph is wrong:

The measurement is taken using two voltmeters, one connected parallel to the diode to measure its voltage drop and one connected parallel to the resistor to measure the current in the circuit.
Is it because I'm using too big of a voltage for one diode that the graph becomes linear after 5 V on the diode? The current also seems off.
I have to use only the equipment I listed.
Edit:
Here's a picture of the circuit:

Here's a picture of the diode:

I varied the voltage by adding/ removing diodes and number of batteries.
SOLUTION:
THE DIODE HAD A RESISTOR INSIDE

To avoid ambiguity draw a schematic of your test circuit and provide links to your meters.

How did you vary the voltage?  Your measurements make no sense.

Voltage across an LED is 14V? For red I'd expect 2.0V tops, for blue maybe 4V. 14V is nonsense, unless it's one of those with an integrated resistor, in which case you aren't measuring diode voltage, rather you are measuring voltage across the combined diode & resistor, and the slope of the graph (which seems somewhat constant) is dominated by and representative of the resistance.

Hi, I updated the post

But you are not measuring the UI curve of the diode. You are not using the U of the diode but the batteries. No wonder the curve makes sense for the diode. If you change by 1V from 14V to 15V, the milliamps is going to increase approximately by 1mA as you have approximately 1 kohm resistor.

How do I measure the voltage of the diode then?

From your deescription and photo, you are measuring the voltage across the diode.  For a plain red diode, you should not measure much over 2.0 V.  If you measuring more than that, you must have a diode with a built-in resistor or current limiting circuit - some LEDs that look like plain LEDs actually have a built-in resistor, and would be advertised as "5V" or "12V" LEDs.

A very original way to regulate the current through the LED under test... If this is your idea, congratulations!
